# JavaScript initEvent not firing more than once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am creating Chrome extension where I create custom event called `STATUS` in my html page..

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("STATUS", true, false);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I dispatch this event (`STATUS`) every page load, but I get fired only on first page load this following script is in content script of chrome extension.

```
window.addEventListener("STATUS", function( event ) { 
console.log( 'init event called' );
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "STATUS" });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Race condition issues? It depends where (or rather, when) you inject your content script.

Your event probably fires before the listener is active. Try changing `run_at` for content script to `"document_start"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following script

```
var event = new CustomEvent( "STATUS", {bubbles: true,cancelable: true} );
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

listener script

```
window.addEventListener("STATUS", function( event ) { 
  console.log( ' event called' );

});
```

creating event using initEvent is depreceated. Please refer following link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#The_old-fashioned_way